# Creating a Java (for desktop) Flashcards Program

Tags: java

I am in the process of designing my first real Java Program for desktop that will be a FlashCards program, that will later be transferred to Android. My question is this - what would be the best option to save the user's flashcards and keep them on file so when the user opens the program again, his flashcards will be there until deleted (by the user).

Comment: What about a database? Android supports SQLite very well.

Answer (score 1):

Well you have two options according to my opinion. In Java either store in the file system, or use a database. In Android, i think SQLite is your only option to store data. I know that android can store preferences as well, but i guess this is not suitable for your case.

SQLite is a very good option, as you can have it in Java(needs a touch of configuration) and Android(already there) too.

Comment: On the desktop you could store data in something like a data.dat, you could do the same on Android, you could write your data to a file and read/write the file according to the program usage.  However, i would agree that SQLite is a much better and preferable option.